# Catching exceptions in external jar classes in Java

Tags: java, exception, jar, classloader

I have a project in java that has its own exception handler (that implements UncaughtExceptionHandler).

This exception handler works for all classes within the project file. However, we are also loading external jars as plugins for our program. The custom exception handler doesn't work with the jar files that I implement using Java's URLClassLoader class.

Throwing an exception in any of the classes of these plugin jar files causes the exceptions to be swallowed. The stack trace isn't even printed to the console.

Any idea how I can get my main project's default exception handler to handle the cases for these external classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Do your third party libraries create separate threads ? As far as I remember, UncaughtExceptionHandler is associated to a given Thread.

Comment: They are running on the same thread. Calling Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() in the main project and the plugin class (where the exceptions are being swallowed) returns the same Exception Handler.

Comment: Do you see the error messages when you disable the handler ?

Comment: No, I've tried disabling it and the stack trace still isn't printed to console.